# Rmd file opens instead of HTML in browser

Tags: r, shiny

I have a file test1.rmd.

[image]

On clicking Knit internal window opens. When I click "open in Browser",it shows this output in .rmd and not in .html.

[image]

**When I include Output: html_document, the display is all messed up.** 
How can I keep the same view/display when converting to html from rmd?

Comment: Could you please provide the .rmd file in question?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? which version?

Comment: R Studio- Version 0.99.903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour when you use `shiny` in your rmarkdown document. RStudio starts a temporary Shiny Server which serves your Rmd file so that users can interact with it. As the `shiny` elements need to run with a Shiny Server, it cannot be contained in a pure HTML file.